# How to mutate an STVector?

Tags: haskell, vector, state, mutable

`MVector` comes in two flavors, `IOVector` and `STVector`. I want to write some functions that use `STVector`, so that they can be called from pure code despite using the fast mutable-vector algorithms in `Data.Vector.Algorithms`.

With the help of [a related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579959/how-to-put-mutable-vector-into-state-monad), I've gotten partway there: I can stick an immutable `Vector` into a mutable `ST` context:

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Vector
import Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro (sort)

x = fromList [1,4,2] :: Vector Int

verboseCopy :: Vector Int
verboseCopy = runST $ do v <- thaw x
                         freeze v
```

I just need to run `sort` between the thaw and the freeze.

Perhaps surprisingly, I did not have to `import Data.Vector.Mutable`, which is where `STVector` is defined. Maybe I should use a type signature to specify that I want `thaw` to produce an `STVector`, but I don't know how: If I change the `thaw` line to this:

```
v <- thaw x :: Data.Vector.Mutable.STVector s Int
```

I get this error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘MVector
                                  (primitive-0.6.3.0:Control.Monad.Primitive.PrimState (ST s))
                                  Int’
              with actual type ‘Int’
• In the first argument of ‘freeze’, namely ‘v’
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be fine to write:

```
verboseCopy :: Vector Int
verboseCopy = runST $ do v <- thaw x
                         sort v
                         freeze v
```

giving:

```
> verboseCopy
[1,2,4]
>
```

The `sort v` performs the sort as a side effect on the mutable vector `v`, so there's no need to "save" or "capture" the sort result, if that's what you were worried about.

You don't need to explicitly type `v`.  Haskell will infer it to be a mutable vector and will treat it appropriately as an `IOVector` or `STVector` depending on whether you are using it within the IO or ST monad.

For your information, the reason you're getting the error is that the type you're supplying is for `v`, but you've applied it to `thaw x` which has a more complex type.  If you write:

```
verboseCopy :: Vector Int
verboseCopy = runST $ do v <- thaw x :: ST s (STVector s Int)
                         sort v
                         freeze v
```

then it'll type check.  However, again, this is unnecessary and won't change the behavior at all.  Haskell has already figured out this type for you.